# Does a dynamic DNS hide your ip adress?

Tags: dns

I'm setting up a self hosted server on my own network.
I don't want my ip address to be easily discovered as it's also my home ip address.

I was wondering if setting a dynamic DNS such as Duck DNS would allow to hide it to most users.
If no is there a solution to hide it ?

Post scriptum : The server is running on debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Setting up DNS would not hide the IP address. You can check with quite easily by using the `host` utility on Linux for instance:

```
host stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.129.69
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.193.69
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.65.69
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.1.69
```

So even if you setup your own hostname, everybody will know the IP anyway. Because in order to connect to your hostname, software will look up the IP and connect to that. If you want to hide your IP, you need to use a for instance a VPN.

Answer (score -1):

Get a cheap VPS with enough bandwidth and use it as proxy, then disclose the proxy IP istead of the origin one.